# Is it a compound sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, syntactic-analysis, sentence, compound-sentences

I found this question on the SAT Practice Test. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

<Today, being white- collar doesn't just mean working in an office, it means having the power to decide the fates of blue-collar workers.>

As far as I know, we can connect clauses in a compound sentence in one of the following ways:

1. coordinate conjunction
2. coordinate conjunction + comma
3. semi-colon
4. semi-colon + conjunctive adverb + comma
5. colon
6. comma [only if there is a list of clauses - 3 or more clauses]

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: @John Lawler, would you please be kind to explain why?

Comment: @JohnLawler How is this grammatical? Correct me if I'm wrong (which I probably am), but wouldn't you need to add a coordinating conjunction between "office" and "it" (or one of the other ways listed by the OP)?  Are you seeing "being white-colar...an office" as a nonrestrictive clause (also, are independent clauses even allowed to be nonrestrictive)?  Sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm quite confused.

Comment: A coordinating conjunction would be fine, but it would be inferred here anyway. The fact that both clauses use the same subject and verb, and contrast their direct objects allows the coordinate structure to be inferred, the way it is when we delete the first 2 _and_'s in _Bob, Carol, Ted, and Alice_. The intonation isn't right for a comma, but it's not a full stop, either. There isn't a punctuation mark that would fit, since language is alive but printing isn't.

Comment: @JohnLawler, thanks a lot. Now it makes sense. Could we have the reference to the rule, if there is one?

Comment: If it matters, it's a compound-complex sentence because both conjoined clauses have subordinate clauses. As it turns out, most English utterances are either not complete sentences, or else complex-compound sentences. Simple sentences are rare. So rare that they can be used for emphasis.

Comment: @JohnLawler, where are the subordinate clauses though?

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand that this sentence can be understood by someone reading/listening to it, but I still don't think it is grammatical (in a formal context).  What do you think about its use in formal writing?

Comment: If you think it's ungrammatical, you should be able to state the rules that it's violating and where they are documented (and who issues them). Otherwise it's just your opinion, and who knows where that came from? As to what I think about "formal writing", I did formal writing for a living for 40 years and it's much overrated. The only issue in this sentence that has to do with formal writing is the punctuation; I know editors that would change the comma to a semicolon. Otherwise, it's just fine for formal writing.

Comment: @JohnLawler , referring to your own words, Mr. Lawler, could we have the source for why it is grammatical and explanation for how the sentence above is a compound-complex sentence. This is purely for teaching material at school, not for criticism.

Comment: I'll provide an answer, then, if you'll link it to your students.

Comment: @JohnLawler, you mean I will have to cite the stackexchange message as an explanation?

Comment: You'd have to quote me as the authority, and I'm publishing here. Because you asked the question here in public.